# 3 contestants choosing a smallest number to win a car

Tags: game-theory

Each of 3 contestants chooses a positive integer. The contestant who chooses the unique smallest positive integer number wins a car. If all of them chose the same number, then no body wins car. What is the optimal strategy?

I do not know how this is done, so I can only guess.

The players should play the same strategy, by the nature of the game. 
I started off assuming that it makes no sense choosing 4 or above (so I assumed one should choose 1,2 or 3).

After some algebra bashing, I arrived at the result.

maximise  $x(1-x)^2 + y(x^2+(1-x-y)^2)+(1-x-y)(x^2+y^2)$ subject to the condition $x+y\leq 1$

Somewhat surprisingly, this expression in symmetric in x and y. I used the Language's multiplier and arrive at $x=y=4/3-\sqrt{40}/6$, which is about 0.28.

This suggest the contestants should choose 1 or 2 with probability 0.28 and choose 3 with probability 0.44. The chance of winning is about 0.29.

However, it is clear that this is not the optimal strategy. If players A and B uses such strategy, then C can choose 1 or 2 with probability 1/2, then he has about > 0.5 chance of winning.

I suspected that the optimal strategy is all players choose 1 or 2 with probability 1/2. I seem to find is no way of deviating from this strategy which would improve each player's pay off. Is this right? how do we prove this?

Comment: If you could choose a number at random, wouldn't it be too big to write down?

Comment: @JohnDouma i meant you just choose an integer.

Comment: Are the players allowed to agree on a common strategy between them?

Comment: @Aretino in which case, if the other two play 1 or 2 with probability 1/2. everyone still have 1/4 chance of winning. If everyone think like that, no body wins.

Comment: @Aretino I assume no. if they are, then they should sign a contract and throw a dice, the person with highest number gets to pick 1, giving each person 1/3 of chance of winning.

Comment: @Lost1 Integers can be negative. Since there are an infinite number of them, no matter what technology you used to represent them, a random number would in all likelihood be too large in absolute value to write down.

Comment: Okay, suppose $C$ was playing the strategy you proposed. Would her performance improve if she simply said $1$ every time?

Comment: @JohnDouma The question states 'the smallest unique positive integers' wins.

Comment: @Lost1 Actually, wait, I'm a little confused now. Who wins if the choices were $(1,1,2)$? Nobody, or the third person?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 the person who chooses 2. Basically I think we want a strategy which maximises the individual chance of winning but penalises people from deviating. If the choice was (1,1,1), then nobdy wins.

Comment: Ah, cool. I thought you were just picking up the whole Nash eqb. spiel, and was going to do a long comment based thing taking you to the solution of the competition game :P

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I am vaguely aware of the concept of nash equilibrium concept but I am not sure how we prove it in this case. in a perfectly rational world, the players would probably collude...

Comment: Okay, anyway, assuming there isn't some sort of cooperation going on, the symmetry of the problem suggests that a symmetric N.E. exists, suppose over some set of integers $[1:N]$. Try assuming some $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_N$, and calculating costs, and finally optimising over $N$?

Comment: I don't quite know how to write down the max min (?) problem.

Comment: I posted a long-winded answer, which hopefully builds some intuition. Feel free to throw questions at me, although I may be a while before answering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll try to formulate something that hopefully makes sense. This is long mainly because you're relatively unfamiliar with game theory, and I want to make sure that you *get* what is happening here. I get a bit hand-wavy at parts, sorry about that. Oh, also, the more usual, simple version of this is called the Competition Game, which is a good way to see how results can be weird when you're new to game theory. Check it out.

The assumptions are the following:

1. The players are not cooperating.
2. The players want to individually maximise their expected benefit, (which is $1$ when they get the car, and $0$ otherwise)

Suppose instead of all positive integers, we were looking at positive integers up to some $N$, and $A$ put some probability distribution $p_A$ on them: $A$ samples the space of possible moves with $p_A$ and plays the result. $A$ wants to choose the $p_A$ such that her chance of winning the car is maximised given that $B$ and $C$ are running their own strategies $p_B$ and $p_C$. But the symmetry of the problem - all three are in the identical situation- suggests that whatever $p_A$ she decides, $B$ and $C$ will also decide the same. So she can assume $p_A$, $p_B$, $p_C$ are identical, some $p$. The thing left to choose is the actual $p_k$ and cardinality $N$.

(I waved my hands a bit there, and if you want to learn a more precise and general version of this idea, pick up a good game theory text. Actually, even the wiki page isn't too bad. This essentially defines a mixed Nash Equilibirium, and Nash famously showed that this exists, so we're not in too much hot water)

So, from any one player's point of view, you have three i.i.d random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3 \sim p$, and we're interested in the optimisation problem

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{p, N}{\text{max}}
& & P(X_1 < X_2, X_1 < X_3) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & p_k = 0, \; i \notin [1: N] \\
& & & \sum_1^N p_k = 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

(Note that this is strictly less than $1/3$. Herein lies the difference with the cooperative case. $A$ could have just played a random over numbers of the form $3k$, $B$ over $3k+1$, $C$ over $3k+2$, and they'd have essentially made their chances of winning a car the same, which is anyway enforced, and maximum. The reason they can't do that here is obvious - even if they realised that this was the best way to go, there's no way to ensure that they'd pick the right parities.)

This may or may not be easy to solve. Intuitively, the optimal strategy seems to be that to find a very large $N$ and uniformly sample over $[1:N]$, so that the chance of collisions is small, and the individual probabilities of winning as close to $1/3$ as possible.

(There are technical issues with this, the main one being that distributions over the natural number don't really exists)

Note however, why the strategy you suggest is unstable: Suppose I have a strategy that mean I will win with probability $x$, and there exists a strategy that increases this chance, I will definitely switch to it. This would affect the chances of my opponents winning, and if they find that they can do better with something else, given that I'm now playing this new strategy, they will switch as well. This would either keep going on forever, or we'll hit some sort of fixed point, where changing is detrimental to all players, and stay there. Nash showed that at least one fixed point exists.

Comment: the optimal strategy cannot be over a large number surely? If 2 players do this, i can just choose 1 and 2 with probability 1/2 to beat this strategy. At the top, you said your assumption is the players are not cooperating, but settling for a distribution which make the prob of winning as close to 1/3 as possible is collusion.

Comment: So this just seems like a 3 player prisoner dilemma problem. The only stable point is everyone chooses 1 and nobody win. If two player sample over 1 to N uniformly, i am going to pick 1 every time...

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But I don't buy that the stable point would be picking $1$ every time, simply because symmetry implies everyone would do that,  so it's beneficial to pick $2$ *sometime*.

Comment: In my head this seems to suggest that the strategies would expand to any arbitrary $n$, but I may simply be underestimating the weight that one would start putting on the lower numbers. Perhaps it'd be better to actually solve the optimisation problem?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a Nash equilibrium, and the other two are playing it, then it doesn't matter what number the first player plays.  So if the others play with probability distribution p(1)=a,p(2)=b,p(3)=c,
First player wins playing 1 with probability $(1-a)^2$
First player wins playing 2 with probability $a^2+c^2$
First player wins playing 3 with probability $a^2+b^2$
So $(1-a)^2=a^2+c^2=a^2+b^2,a+b+c=1$
which has solution $a=2\sqrt{3}-3,b=2-\sqrt{3},c=2-\sqrt{3}$ and 
first player wins with probability $28-16\sqrt{3}=0.287$
If they use four numbers, then $(1-a)^2=a^2+(1-a-b)^2=a^2+b^2+d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$
and Wolfram says the chance of a win is 0.294
When more numbers are used, it seems that $a/b,b/c,c/d,...$ all approach the same ratio.  That gives this solution for infinitely many:
$$(a_1,a_2,...)=a_1(1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,...)\\a_1=1-x$$
Then, using $$(1-a_1)^2=a_1^2+(1-a_1-a_2)^2\\x^2=(1-x)^2+x^4\\x^3+x^2+x=1$$
we get the value of $x=0.5437$ for the Nash equilibrium, with a win probability of $(1-a_1)^2=0.2956$

Comment: I got the same numbers, so does this mean this game has no nash equilibrium?

Comment: If the players play this, one of the player should always choose 1 and have greater than 0.5 percent chance of winning

Comment: If one player chooses 1, that only wins if no-one else does, which happens with probability $(1-a)^2=(4-2\sqrt{3})^2=0.287$

Comment: @Lost1: These are not the same numbers as yours. Not only are the values slightly different, more importantly here $a\gt b=c$ whereas you have $c\gt a=b$. Your values indeed don't constitute a Nash equilibrium; it's not clear to me from the question how you arrived at them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no optimal strategy of the form "everyone follows this given probability distribution: pick $i$ with probability $p_i$".

Indeed, everyone will follow the same strategy if there is an optimal one, so the probability that anyone wins is equal and is at most 1. That is, the four things that can happen are "I win", "Player 2 wins", "Player 3 wins", "no-one wins", and these cover the entire range of options. The first three have equal probability, so it turns out that an optimal strategy is characterised precisely by the need to minimise the probability that no-one wins.

The probability that no-one wins is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^3$, the probability that everyone picks the same number. We wish to minimise this while ensuring that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i = 1$.

But we can pick $p_i$ so that this has arbitrarily small sum, as can be seen with Lagrange multipliers: there is no optimal strategy of this form. For any distribution you give me, I can give you a better one.

However, if everyone adopts the strategy "Pick one of the first $N$ integers at random", then there is probability $\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3 n^3}$ of me (and hence of any given person) winning. That is, with collaboration, you can make the probability of someone winning arbitrarily close to 1.

Comment: I am slightly confused. In prisoner's dilemma, both criminal should turn their friend in when they are not colluding. Your last sentence suggestions collusion? While this is in a way, optimal, it is certainly unstable.

Comment: @Lost1 The final paragraph does require collusion, yes. The rest of my answer works without collusion, and shows that without collusion, no optimal strategy has the form "pick a probability distribution over the integers, and everyone play according to that strategy".

Comment: Fixing an N, you can do better, as shown in the n=3 case above, what you offered is not optimal when assuming this upper bound, but I see your point.

Comment: @Lost1 There is no way for all participants to fix an $N$, though. If I know that everyone else has fixed $N$, I can just increase my $N$ and do better than them. Therefore there is no equilibrium where everyone has fixed $N$.